# Detect click on text in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have created a text field that the user shall be able to click on

```
Text(
    text = "Test",
    fontSize = 220.sp,
    color = White,
    Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = {
            // Do something
        })
)
```

The compiler does not like this at all, but is also not very helpful in correcting the issue:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
> public fun Text(text: AnnotatedString, modifier: Modifier = ..., color: Color = ..., fontSize: TextUnit = ..., fontStyle: FontStyle? = ..., fontWeight: FontWeight? = ..., fontFamily: FontFamily? = ..., letterSpacing: TextUnit = ..., textDecoration: TextDecoration? = ..., textAlign: TextAlign? = ..., lineHeight: TextUnit = ..., overflow: TextOverflow = ..., softWrap: Boolean = ..., maxLines: Int = ..., inlineContent: Map<String, InlineTextContent> = ..., onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = ..., style: TextStyle = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material3
> public fun Text(text: String, modifier: Modifier = ..., color: Color = ..., fontSize: TextUnit = ..., fontStyle: FontStyle? = ..., fontWeight: FontWeight? = ..., fontFamily: FontFamily? = ..., letterSpacing: TextUnit = ..., textDecoration: TextDecoration? = ..., textAlign: TextAlign? = ..., lineHeight: TextUnit = ..., overflow: TextOverflow = ..., softWrap: Boolean = ..., maxLines: Int = ..., onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = ..., style: TextStyle = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material3

What is a correct and simple way to create a text field the user can click on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use the `clickable{}` lamdas to make `Text` clickable.

Example

```
@Composable
fun ExpandableTextExample() {
    Text(text = "Demo Clickable Text", modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        Log.d(TAG, "ExpandableTextExample: Detect Click")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was that you forgot `modifier =`, as you see on the error log modifier comes second.

For whatever reason you do not want to use `modifier =` you should write it as:

```
Text(
    text = "Test",
    Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = {
            // Do something
        }),
    fontSize = 220.sp,
    color = White
)
```

or with named arguments:

```
Text(
    text = "Test",
    fontSize = 220.sp,
    color = White,
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = {
            // Do something
        })
)
```